# search a string in text file using windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I am trying to check if a particular string (`Lost = 0`) in a text file `out.txt` and echoing the result to a text file depends upon the error level.If the string is present in the text file, I need to echo service is up otherwise service is down.

I am using below code, but its not working.I am always getting out as `service is up`  Can you please let me know what is the issue with the script ?

```
echo off

findstr  /c:"Lost = 0" "out.txt" >nul

if ERRORLEVEL 1 ( @echo service is up >result.txt 

) else (

@echo service is down >result.txt)
```

Comment: Is the service always up? Have you tested an out.txt file containing "Lost = 0"?

Comment: @lit:yes I tried with Lost = 0, even completely removing that line. but still getting  service is up message

Comment: I get "service is down" in the result.txt file. Sorry. I am not sure I can help.

Comment: what's the encoding of out.txt? if it's UTF-16 you have to use `find` not `findstr`

Comment: If the error level is 1, that means it was not found in the file, which from your description means the service is down.

Comment: Post a sample input file that yields the stated results.

Comment: @jwdonahue I tried with a normal notepad and added some random text without "Lost = 0".

Comment: @Squashman I tried changing with ERRORLEVEL 0 and out.txt without the search word. Still I am getting service is up message

Comment: @acr no that is not the correct way to do it. Your code should say if errorlevel 1 (echo service is down) else (echo service is up)

Comment: @Squashman Thanks. I have changed the code accordingly. Now I have error at  'findstr  /c:"Lost = 0" "out.txt" >nul' giving me FIND: Invalid switch error. I will  check the syntax

Comment: Are you using FIND or FINDSTR?

Comment: @Squashman I was using FIND. Now changed to FINDSTR. Its working perfectly now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of checking the error level you can check the matched string using `for /F` with a given delimiter ("=" in this case):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('
    findstr /c:"Lost =" "out.txt"
') do set str=%%E

if "%str%" == " 0" (echo service is up) else (echo service is down)
```

Take care with the token and the resulting string. In your case the 2nd token is " *n*" (with leading space) and n the value of *Lost*.